# SQL Server backup issue

Tags: sql-server, backup, windows-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise on Windows Server 2008 x64. I want to run daily job at mid-night every day to make full backup of database. Any reference document to follow for a newbie of this topic?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the Maintenance Plan wizard, to set up a nightly backup.

Later, read about backups in Books Online and Paul Randal's blog.

Comment: "Maintenance Plan wizard" -- how to start this wizard?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a job to the SQL Server Agent, it's in your object explorer when you log on with MSSMS.

But I think it's better to ask this on serverfault.com

Comment: I know how to add a job to SQL Server Agent, I want to know how to implement the job to do a full backup of database. Sorry, I am a newbie to do maintenance. :-)

Comment: I do not know how to write a job to do database backup, can you recommend me some samples please? I am previously working on ADO.Net programming, the DBA is OOF, and I am doing some maintenance job -- so I say I am a newbie of maintenance. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run backup nightly you most likely using the computer account instead of a domain user account. 
So you might need to login and 
connect with the network service account (if for remote server db backup) by using the computer account instead of a domain user. To enable backups from specific computers to a shared drive, grant access to the computer accounts. Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35a8e100-3ff2-4844-a5da-dd088c43cba4#BackupFileUsingPhysicalName).